# Can I navigate backwards by word (not WORD) in command-line mode?

Tags: command-line, navigation

If I'm in command-line mode in vim, and I have the current command line entered (cursor position shown with `|`):

```
:somecommand somefilename.txt|
```

I'd like to navigate backwards so that the cursor is behind the `.`:

```
:somecommand somefilename|.txt
```

Is there a way I can do this with a single command? In normal mode, I could use `bb` to move back two words, but it seems that the only keybinding I can find in command line mode that's relevant to words is Shift-Left, and this moves by *WORDS*, not *words* (i.e. it ignores all punctuation and only looks at whitespace), so the cursor ends up here:

```
:somecommand |somefilename.txt
```

If it's relevant, I would like to use this as part of a mapping, so it doesn't matter if it's a bit fiddly to type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't mind a mapping, we can use

```
cnoremap <S-Left> <C-f>bb<C-c>
```

This remaps `<S-Left>` to the behavior you described, using `<C-f>` to switch to edit the command line in normal mode. `<C-c>` then switches back to command line mode.

For details, refer to `:h cmdline-window`

Comment: Great, thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a built-in way to do it with bare cmdline accroding to `:h cmdline.txt`.

But if you are into heavy edit of the command line I suggest to use `:<C-f>` or `q:` to open command-line window where you can edit it with 'normal' vim commands.

See `:h cmdline-window` for details.

Comment: Thanks, this works. But ugly, but it works!