# Delete from cursor position until end of line in command-line mode

Tags: key-bindings, command-line, insert-mode

I am trying to emulate readline keybindings in insert and command-line modes (for example, `<C-u>` for deleting from cursor position to beginning of the line, or `<C-w>` to delete previous word). The readline action `kill-line` deletes from the current cursor position to the end of the line, and it is usually bound to `<C-k>`. I have managed to emulate it in insert mode with

```
inoremap <Plug>(i_kill-line) <Esc>lC
imap <C-k> <Plug>(i_kill-line)
```

How could I do something similar in command-line mode?

Comment: I understand you may still want to do things as you describe but are you familiar with the [command-line window](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/31466/11054)? It's a great way to do command-line editing. You can use the full power of Vim rather than a smattering of Vim-like keystrokes.

Comment: C-u and C-w should already work insert mode. At any rate for command-line mode you need cnoremap, and as BLayer says the command-line window makes editing even nicer.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I am aware of the command-line window and I should probably use it more. However, I like to have the same basic keybindings in the main places where I can type (mainly Bash, Vim and fzf window) because that makes it easier to learn them and use them mechanically. `<C-k>` was recently added to my vocabulary, so I wanted to make it available in Vim.

Comment: @mgarort `set -o vi` :)

Comment: Indeed :) But I find simple emacs keybindings more appropriate for the command line, and also I have personalized Vim in a way that `set -o vi` cannot replicate. So I would have a similar problem of non-homogeneity with `set -o vi`.

Comment: I had the same question (why I'm here): I wanted to have the same bindings in VI, terminal, and Mutt. it bothers me a bit that this doesn't seem to be a more popular question. makes me think there's something wrong with wanting to do this!

Comment: I think it goes slightly against the "Vim philosophy" of doing most changes in normal mode. However, I believe these bindings are extremely useful. In case you're interested, these are all my bindings to emulate readline https://github.com/mgarort/dotvim/blob/master/plugin/readline.vim  but there are probably complete plugins out there that you can install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use combination of `:h c_CTRL-\_e`, `:h getcmdline()` and `:h getcmdpos()`:

```
func! KillLineToEnd()
    return strpart(getcmdline(), 0, getcmdpos()-1)
endfunc
cnoremap <C-k> <C-\>eKillLineToEnd()<CR>
```

Comment: Very impressive. Thank you!