# Normal mode command in Command-line mode

Tags: command-line, normal-mode

I'm in the process of mapping MacOS keybindings (Cmd/Alt + arrows/backspace/delete) to Vim commands, and the only thing remaining is to make the movements in normal mode (such as `b` or `e`) work in the command line :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VI mode when using colon (:)](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/31465/vi-mode-when-using-colon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin’s answer with `:normal[!]` is great for running Normal commands from an Ex command.

Two other possible interpretations:

- In a (Normal-mode) mapping, the right-hand side *is* Normal mode. So `nnoremap <M-w> db` is fine if you can use Meta mappings.
- To use Normal-mode editing features on the Ex/`:` command line, press `q:` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd> while already in `:`. The latter works for searches as well and may be customized. For the former, cf. `q/` and `q?`.

Answer (score 1):

The :normal command seems to be what you're looking for; there are two variants of this: `:normal` may use custom mappings from your vimrc or plugins, if any, and `:normal!` will always use the default built-in Vim mappings. For example, this will run `gj`, which is usually unexpected:

```
nnoremap j gj
normal j
```

You usually want to use `:normal!` with the exclamation mark, unless you have a specific reason to use `:normal`.

To use modifiers or named keys, wrap it inside `:execute` (or `:exe` for short); for example:

```
exe "normal! \<C-x>\<C-u>"
```

Comment: Yeah I meant normal mode commands to operate on the _Command line_, not on the buffer, but thanks!